# How to make a remote Sql Server connection in c++?

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I developed an application that accesses the database locally.
Now, how to make this application access the database on another computer in the same network?

This is my connection:

```
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=XXXXXXXX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=XXXXX;uid=sa;pwd=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=Yes");
```

Comment: Assuming you properly sort out all the networking issues (DNS, firewalls/AV, permissions) and make sure the SQL server accepts TCP/IP connections then all you need to change is the server name.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. 
I just put the name of the machine where the database is hosted.